# How can I create a local configs for Neovim extending the global init.vim?

Tags: neovim

Suppose that I have a map on my init.vim that I want to change the behaviour depending on the folder that I am. How could you do that?

A more concrete example: I have a map on my F12 that runs the project that I am. So if I am on a python project, this F12 will run an ipython on a floaternew window, with the current file already imported. Though, if I am on a cpp project, the same F12 will build using Make and running the binary on a floaternew window as well.

Nowadays, I have these two behaviours mapped on different key bindings. But It is going to very nice if I have only one binding to "run the project". Even if I need to open neovim with some parameter in each project, like `neovim --local-config mylocalconfig.vim` (extending init.vim with some behaviour)

I am kind inspired by a behaviour like `direnv` but with `.vim` files.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=727 , https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393 Found in https://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=local+project&script_type=utility&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search

Comment: For language-dependent settings you'd better use filetype-plugins: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in vim `set exrc` which enables reading vim config files from current directory, it also works in neovim.

From docs (`:h exrc`)

> Enables the reading of .vimrc, .exrc and .gvimrc in the current
> directory.  If you switch this option on you should also consider
> setting the 'secure' option (see |initialization|).  Using a local
> .exrc, .vimrc or .gvimrc is a potential security leak, use with care!
> also see |.vimrc| and |gui-init|.
> This option cannot be set from a |modeline| or in the |sandbox|, for
> security reasons.

Update, since neovim 0.9.0 *exrc* option will look for *init.lua* first and afterwards will check for *.nvimrc*.