# Is it possible to automatically use LSP with project local settings in Neovim?

Tags: virtualenv, neovim

I'm using NeoVim and LSP (coc.nvim) as IDE.
Now, I install IDE tools in each project as devdependencies, and configure global Vim setting that which IDE tools are used.

I want to configure IDE tool settings in each project, then Vim to read it and select tools automatically.
Is there any way for this situation?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464096/how-can-i-create-a-local-configs-for-neovim-extending-the-global-init-vim/70464164#70464164) answer you question?

Comment: Hmm, I feel like it solves my question.  
Then, I reached [this page](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/Project-local-settings).  
Ideally, I want not to place the project local setting file that depends on specific editor. (e.g. we place JSON or YAML setting file and each editor reads it.)  
I understood I need to create new plugin that satisfies my demand.  
Thanks your comment!