# per-directory netrw settings

Tags: vim, neovim, netrw

Is there a way to have directory specific netrw settings in (neo)vim? I want to keep my default settings in my `.vimrc` but for some directories, I want netrw to use -- for example -- the tree view instead of the flat one, maybe a different sorting, etc.

Is there a way to achieve that?

I checked the netrw help but couldn't find anything related. I do also remember some setting in vim that allowed for per-directory settings, but I don't remember the concrete option, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464096/how-can-i-create-a-local-configs-for-neovim-extending-the-global-init-vim/70464164#70464164

With that you can provide different settings per folder.