# is it possible to have nvim use two different themes for different use cases?

Tags: neovim

I am new to `nvim` (neovim).

I use `mutt` for my mailing needs. For editor, I use `nvim` for which I am using the theme `bluz71/vim-nightfly-colors` however, I feel that it would be helpful to have the mutt invocation to `/usr/bin/nvim` for editing images have a different them (say, `overcache/NeoSolarized` light theme). So, basically, I want `mutt` to call the `nvim` editor with a different theme than when I invoke `nvim` for some other editing case. Is this possible to do? Is there some other way we can do this?

Update: following the suggestions given by @lcheylus, I made a `.vim/ftplugin/mail.vim` file and put `colorscheme NeoSolarized` in it.
I also added `filetype plugin on` in my `.config/nvim/init.vim` and added the following to my `.vim/filetype/mail.vim`:

```
set termguicolors
set background=light
colorscheme NeoSolarized


" Default value is "normal", Setting this option to "high" or "low" does use the
" same Solarized palette but simply shifts some values up or down in order to
" expand or compress the tonal range displayed.
let g:neosolarized_contrast = "normal"

" Special characters such as trailing whitespace, tabs, newlines, when displayed
" using ":set list" can be set to one of three levels depending on your needs.
" Default value is "normal". Provide "high" and "low" options.
let g:neosolarized_visibility = "normal"

" I make vertSplitBar a transparent background color. If you like the origin
" solarized vertSplitBar style more, set this value to 0.
let g:neosolarized_vertSplitBgTrans = 1

" If you wish to enable/disable NeoSolarized from displaying bold, underlined
" or italicized" typefaces, simply assign 1 or 0 to the appropriate variable.
" Default values:
let g:neosolarized_bold = 1
let g:neosolarized_underline = 1
let g:neosolarized_italic = 0

" Used to enable/disable "bold as bright" in Neovim terminal. If colors of bold
" text output by commands like `ls` aren't what you expect, you might want to
" try disabling this option. Default value:
let g:neosolarized_termBoldAsBright = 1
```

that appears to work for me in making my NeoSolarized theme to light.

Comment: You can try providing custom local config for _mutt_ in a  folder where neovim is being launched by it. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70464164/6482931) about local configs,. Better solution from [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293456/setting-editor-in-mutt-vim-with-parameters) there are examples how to provide custom options for _mutt_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set specific commands for mail (Mutt in your case) via a `ftplugin/mail.vim` configuration file.

To set your colorscheme via `ftplugin/mail.vim`,

```
colorscheme NeoSolarized
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask more about this: I should create a new directory/folder called .vim/ftplugin and put in there a `mail.vim` with the above? I did try that but did not get anything different at all. That is, the colorscreme did not change to NeoSolarized (light).

Comment: Yes, you need to create `.vim/ftplugin` for the file `mail.vim`. Do you have `filetype plugin on` in your VIM configuration ?